# Data Encryption in C Server

Tags: c, encryption

I am making a relatively simple file transfer server in C.  This server is being developed through the lens of network security.  I know C is an inherently insecure language due to lack of bounds checks (and other problems); however I know it is possible to make data at least somewhat secure in C.
My exact problem is that, the client side will send a password to the server for their folder; however, I would like this password to be encrypted (it isn't as important for the other information, but I might encrypt that too).  What is a good way to encrypt/decrypt a string being sent over a network, in C?

Comment: This probably belongs in Cryptography.

Comment: Use [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) to encrypt your traffic. But you shouldn't encrypt passwords at all. Instead, hash them with a secure password hashing algorithm such as [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).

Answer (score 1):

You will have few issues to solve before you tackle that:

You want to encrypt the data possibly with a symmetric cipher such as AES (you will need to find a library which implements AES in C), and also find out about encryption modes such as CBC etc.

But then comes the question what key will you use with cipher to encrypt your data? So you have arrived at a different issue called key management. The most trivial - and if it is fine in your scenario- could be having a  key stored on the server (this approach is called key pre-distribution) which also the client knows. Anyway, there are many ways to do key management. You would have to read on that too.

---

PS. it is also true that normally you don't encrypt passwords rather - store their hashes. But I answered you anyway in case you may want to encrypt some other information.